# updating MySQL table - You can't specify target table for update in From clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT entity_id AS product_id FROM catalog_product_entity cpe
LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item csi ON csi.product_id = cpe.entity_id
WHERE cpe.type_id = 'configurable'
AND csi.is_in_stock = 0
AND (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM catalog_product_relation cpr LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item cisi ON cisi.product_id = cpr.child_id WHERE cpr.parent_id = cpe.entity_id) > 0
```

Which returns the following results:

```
product_id
-----------
912
906
894
559
364
```

I am trying to update the `is_in_stock` column within the `cataloginventory_stock_item` table, based off of the product_id of the table existing in the results of the above query.

What I tried to do was this:

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item
SET is_in_stock = 1
WHERE product_id IN (
    SELECT entity_id AS product_id FROM catalog_product_entity cpe
    LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item csi ON csi.product_id = cpe.entity_id
    WHERE cpe.type_id = 'configurable'
    AND csi.is_in_stock = 0
    AND (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM catalog_product_relation cpr LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item cisi ON cisi.product_id = cpr.child_id WHERE cpr.parent_id = cpe.entity_id) > 0
)
```

And I receive the following error:
 `You can't specify target table 'cataloginventory_stock_item' for update in FROM clause`

I can't seem to figure out how to restructure the query to work.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In looking at your original statement: the `LEFT JOIN` in the main query ends up being an "INNER JOIN" due to the use of csi.is_in_stock in the WHERE clause. Also, the ambiguity (lack of alias) for `qty` in the subquery makes it hard to know which table it's from; if it's from `cpr`, then the `LEFT JOIN` in the subquery is pointless. Otherwise, it should probably be an `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one by giving the alias to you select query

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item
SET is_in_stock = 1
WHERE product_id IN (
SELECT   new_table.product_id  FROM (

 SELECT entity_id AS product_id FROM catalog_product_entity cpe
    LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item csi ON csi.product_id = cpe.entity_id
    WHERE cpe.type_id = 'configurable'
    AND csi.is_in_stock = 0
    AND (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM catalog_product_relation cpr LEFT JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item cisi ON cisi.product_id = cpr.child_id WHERE cpr.parent_id = cpe.entity_id) > 0
) new_table

)
```

Comment: This worked exactly how I was expecting.  My query may not be efficient, however this was for a quick db fix rather than production implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following multi-table UPDATE does the same thing, without using subqueries:

```
UPDATE cataloginventory_stock_item AS csi
 JOIN catalog_product_entity AS cpe ON csi.product_id = cpe.entity_id
 JOIN catalog_product_relation AS cpr ON cpr.parent_id = cpe.entity_id
 JOIN cataloginventory_stock_item AS cisi ON cisi.product_id = cpr.child_id
SET csi.is_in_stock = 1
WHERE cpe.type_id = 'configurable' AND csi.is_in_stock = 0 AND cisi.qty > 0;
```

I'm assuming that cisi.qty is never negative.  So if any row with qty>0 is found, then SUM(qty) will be greater than zero.

PS: Your original query uses LEFT JOIN as though it's an INNER JOIN.  You should study [how the different types of joins work](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the JOIN.  I'll into them more to better understand their correct usages.